# c# KeyValuePair and database

Tags: c#, ms-access, keyvaluepair

I am doing a c# application project whereby the receptionist is able to book the rooms for the customers. I had created a database whereby it looks like this

```
ID  RoomType    
1   Nap             
2   Nap             
3   Nap             
4   Nap             
5   Nap             
6   Meeting_Small   
7   Meeting_Small   
8   Meeting_Small   
9   Meeting_Small   
10  Meeting_Small   
11  Meeting_Big     
12  Meeting_Big     
13  Meeting_Big     
14  Meeting_Big     
15  Meeting_Big
```

Also, I would like to use the KeyValuePair to link to my access database together through a button. So the receptionist will have to click on the a button to select the room. When the button is selected, the database will show that that particular room is taken.

I tried to code it by coding this under the button.

```
KeyValuePair<String, String> selectedRoom;
selectedRoom = new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Nap", "1");
```

However, I am not sure if this is possible. Can someone help me out? thank you

I had removed the room number out

Comment: Do you really want `Id`? Isn't *RoomNumber* a much better *natural* candidate for being a *primary key*?

Comment: primary Keys never should change... but room numbers can...
so... even if ID and RoomNumber are the same it's usefull to have them splitted